# Wrong directory when executable jar launch by shortcut

Tags: java, jar, directory, shortcut

I create some config file by this method:

> String path = System.getProperty("user.dir" );
>
> writer = new PrintWriter(path+"/configTAB2.txt", "UTF-8");
>
> writer.print("100000000000000000000000000001000000000000001000010000000");
>
> writer.close();

or this method

> writer = new PrintWriter("./configTAB2.txt", "UTF-8");
>
> writer.print("100000000000000000000000000001000000000000001000010000000");
>
> writer.close();

My real problem is that I launch the jar directly by double click the file is create on the same directory than my `.jar` but WHEN I create a shortcut on my desktop file are created on the desktop (not in the same directory than my `.jar`)

Do you have some explanation ?

Comment: Why do not use `System.getProperty("user.home");`. No matter from where you launch the jar , it will check one path only

Comment: Yes why not, that's could be a solution. But i want that all files are in the same directory that the instal directory. For exemple an USB stick or else.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.getProperty("user.dir");` property returns the current working directory

> user.dir User's current working directory

So you get different path regards from where we launch the application.

I would use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to make path fixed (aka `C:\Users\xxxx`).

Comment: yes, but the working directory could'nt change when i use the shortcut on the desktop or directly the double clic on the file in my documents.

That's really me problem, i don't understand why it change.